# Default controller not working on live server

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

when i access URL:- donainname.com then i m getting error 404 Page Not Found

Main_ctrl:-

```
class Main_ctrl extends CI_Controller
{
    function main_page()
    {
         echo "testing page";
     }

}
```

In route.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Main_ctrl/main_page';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

In config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://donainname.com/';
```

Comment: Add an exit; line after the echo "testing page"; and see if works

Comment: not working again getting same error

Comment: If you add a public function __contruct(){ echo "test"; exit; } ?

Comment: what is your Main_ctrl file name `main_ctrl.php` or `Main_ctrl.php` ?

Comment: @noufalcep file name is Main_ctrl

Comment: @Kamae No i m't using any function __contruct()

Comment: In config.php do you have $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; ? And please, could you edit your question and add your .htaccess content?

Comment: .htaccess file is blank and i already set $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; in config.php  file

Comment: @SupportTechcherry I've added an answer because is better to see the code, I can't format a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your .htacces file in your root folder (public_html or www)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I'm guessing you're running an Apache server... If you're running an IIS (Windows) just let me know and I can explain you how to do that.